# Plotting Dose Response Curve from Survival Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, drc

I would like to make a dose response curve from the `library(drc)`, and am stuck on how to prepare my dataset properly in order to make the plot. In particular, I’m struggling how to get my y-axis ready.

I made up a dataframe `(df)` to help clarify what I would like to do.

`df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/TZdjp2JX", header=T)`

Open necessary libraries for today's exercise

`library(drc)`

`library(ggplot2)`

Let’s pretend I like humming birds, and do an experiment with different concentrations of sugar with the goal of seeing which concentration is ideal for humming birds.  I therefore run an experiment in a closed setting (here column “room”), with 4 different sugar concentrations (column concentration), and 10 individual birds per concentration. I also run each experiment with 4 replicates in parallel, which is why there are 4 “rooms”.  After 36 hours (column “time”), I go into the room, and check how many birds survived, creating a “yes/no” variable, or 1 & 0 (here, this is my column “status), where 1==survive, 0==died.

With this dataset, I specifically made it that most survived at concentration 0, 50% survived concentration 1, 25% survived concentration 2, and only 10% survive concentration 3.

My first issue I’m running into is :  how can I turn my y-axis , generated from my “status” column into a percentage? I have done this when I do kaplan-meier survival curves, but that does not work here unfortunately.  Obviously, this should column should go from 0% - 100% (we could call the column "mortality").  After I succeed at doing this, I would like to make a dose response curve that looks like the following (I found this example online, and will directly copy it here to use an example. It is from the ryegrass dataset included in R)

```
ryegrass.LL.4 <- drm(rootl ~ conc, data = ryegrass, fct = LL.3())
```

I must admit, the next steps of code are a little confusing for me.

```
# new dose levels as support for the line
newdata <- expand.grid(conc=exp(seq(log(0.5), log(100), length=100)))
# predictions and confidence intervals
pm <- predict(ryegrass.LL.4, newdata=newdata, interval="confidence")
# new data with predictions
newdata$p <- pm[,1]
newdata$pmin <- pm[,2]
newdata$pmax <- pm[,3]

# plot curve

# need to shift conc == 0 a bit up, otherwise there are problems with coord_trans
ryegrass$conc0 <- ryegrass$conc
ryegrass$conc0[ryegrass$conc0 == 0] <- 0.5
# plotting the curve
ggplot(ryegrass, aes(x = conc0, y = rootl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p, ymin=pmin, ymax=pmax), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p)) +
  coord_trans(x="log") +
  xlab("Ferulic acid (mM)") + ylab("Root length (cm)")
```

[image]

In the end, I would like to generate a similar curve, but with mortality on the y-axis, from 0-100 (starting low, going high) and also display the confidence intervals in a shaded grey area around the regression line.  Meaning, my first step of code should like something like the following:

`model <- drc(mortality ~ Concentration, data=df, fct = LL.3())`  But I'm lost on the "mortality" creation part, and a little bit on the next step with ggplot

Could anyone help me achieve this? From the example from `ryegrass`, I'm perplexed how to translate this to be helpful for my pretend dataset. I hope  someone here is able to help me solve this issue!  Many thanks, and I appreciate any feedback if there are other ways I should have my dataset structured, etc.

-Andy

Comment: The data.frame you made does not have a column called `mortality` is this a calculated column?

Comment: Hi @JustinLandis, no it does not have this column.  It should somehow be calculated from the column "status", meaning from the 0's and 1's.  Does this help?

Comment: Hi Andy, when it comes to concentration, do you know if `1` corresponds with higher levels of sugar, and `3` corresponds with lower levels of sugar? I ask because it seems that there may be a leverage problem with the experiment. Concentration `1` seems to already be in the ball park of the `IC50` value, and without any more data points, say a Concentration `0` (if they are sequential) it is hard to predict  a concentration at which you'd expect a majority of humming birds to live. There is a possible work around but it would be a poor fit at best.

Comment: Hello again @JustinLandis, In this example, i really made up the data just to create an example that I could later adapt to other data sets I have.  But, in my mind while I was creating this question, I was assuming the concentration to be highest at concentration ```1``` and lowest at concentration ```3```.  I hope this info helps. 

If it would be easier, I generated a larger data set with a concentration ```0```, with a very low mortality rate. I have updated the question with the new dataset

Comment: Hello again @JustinLandis: 

Could you explain ```exp(seq(log(0.01), log(10), length = 100))``` to me?  

I tried your code on some of my real datasets, and should the log values be my lowest, and highest concentrations?  or why choose 0.01 and 10?  For example, i have a dataset where the concentration is 45, and if I do not set the second log value to ```log(45)``` and use ```log(10)``` than the plot only has confidence intervals up to 10.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
library(drc)
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'MASS'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     select
#> 
#> 'drc' has been loaded.
#> Please cite R and 'drc' if used for a publication,
#> for references type 'citation()' and 'citation('drc')'.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'drc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     gaussian, getInitial

df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/sH5hCr2J", header=T)
```

Making the `mortality` or as I do here `survival`, can be done easily with the `dplyr` package. This will help perform many calculations. It seems that you are interested in calcuating the percent survival for each Concentration across your four rooms (or replicates). So the first step is to group the data by these columns and then calculate the statistic we want.

```r
df_calc <- df %>%
  group_by(Concentration, room) %>%
  summarise(surv = sum(Status)/n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Concentration'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

I don’t know if Concentration represents arbitrary
Concentration levels so I’m moving forward with the following
assumption:

- 1 == higher levels of sugar, 2 == lower levels of sugar
- Concentrations were coding in log space - so I convert to linear space

```r
df_calc <- mutate(df_calc, conc = exp(-Concentration))
```

Just to be clear, the `conc` variable is just my attempt at having something close to the true known concentrations of the experiment. If your data has the true concentrations, then don't mind this calculation.

```r
df_calc
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   Concentration [3]
#>    Concentration  room  surv   conc
#>            <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1             1     1   0.5 0.368 
#>  2             1     2   0.4 0.368 
#>  3             1     3   0.5 0.368 
#>  4             1     4   0.6 0.368 
#>  5             2     1   0   0.135 
#>  6             2     2   0.4 0.135 
#>  7             2     3   0.2 0.135 
#>  8             2     4   0.4 0.135 
#>  9             3     1   0.2 0.0498
#> 10             3     2   0   0.0498
#> 11             3     3   0   0.0498
#> 12             3     4   0.2 0.0498

mod <- drm(surv ~ conc, data =  df_calc, fct = LL.3())
```

Make new `conc` data points

```r
newdata <- data.frame(conc = exp(seq(log(0.01), log(10), length = 100)))
```

#### EDIT

To respond to your comment I'll explain the above code chunk. Again the `conc` variable is expected to be the unit concentration. In this hypothetical case, we have three concentration levels `c(0.049, 0.135, 0.368)`. For brevity, lets assume the units are `mg of sugar/ml of water`. Our model was fit on these three dose levels with 4 data points per dose level. If we wanted, we could have just plotted the curve between these levels of `c(0.049, 0.368)`, but in this example, I chose `c(0.01, 10) mg/ml` as the domain to plot on. This was just so that we could visualize where the curve would end up based on the model fit. In short, you choose the range that you are interested in most. As I show later - even though we can choose data points outside the range of the experimental data, the confidence intervals are extremely large indicating the model will be unhelpful for those points.

The reason behind casting these values with the `log()` function is to ensure that we are sampling points that look evenly distributed on a log10 scale (most does response curves are plotted with this transformation). Once we get the sequence of 100 points, we use `exp()` to return back to the linear space (which our model was fit on). These values are then used in the `predict` function as the new `dose` levels in conjunction with the fitted model.

All this is saved into `newdata` variable which allows for the plotting of the line and the confidence intervals.

Use the model and the generated data points to
predict a new `surv` value as well as the upper and lower bound

```r
newdata <- cbind(newdata,
                 suppressWarnings(predict(mod, newdata = newdata, interval="confidence")))
```

plot with `ggplot2`

```r
ggplot(df_calc, aes(conc)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = surv)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), data = newdata, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Prediction), data = newdata) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

As you may notice, the confidence intervals increase greately when we try and
predict ranges that has no data.

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello

Great.  Thanks for the detailed response.  I do know the real concentrations in my other experiments.  Let me try and run your code, and see what the output is and I will get back to you.  It's night time here, so I will write again tomorrow morning.  

Looking forward to trying it out. !!!